# Exchange server relay

Tags: exchange, smtp

I'm currently trying to configure our exchange 2010 to be used as a external smtp relay. What I'm trying to do is allow certain websites that we manage to send email using our exchange server smtp relay. I was told that I needed to created a receiver connector under Server Configuration>Hub Transport. After I created the receiver connector I added the following confi in which I added the website IP address in the "Receiver mail from remote servers ect" then unders Authentication I selected Externally Secured,TLS and under permissions I selected exchange servers.

I went to one of our websites and configure it with this configuration and I'm still getting "SMTP connect failed."

Can someone help me? or what is the proper way to get this to work. Multiple websites are going to be using this exchanger server SMTP relay in a secure way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how your external web servers will authenticate with the Exchange server. If they do not pass along credentials, then you will need to configure the receive connector to allow anonymous access, you can then set it to deny all access except for the IP addresses of your web servers. It is also wise to change the port that it operates on, especially if it might receive mail from internal sources on port 25.

See here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232021(v=exchg.141).aspx

Once you're confident about the configuration and it's still not working, start looking at your networking for any possible port blocks.